# Have curses keep loading even while not focused?

Tags: python, curses

I am trying to recreate this snippet of code:

```py
from ctypes import windll
from os import system
from keyboard import is_pressed

main_window_handle = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
unfocused_prompt_setting = True

def basic_arrow_selection(options: [str]) -> str:
    '''
    Function for handling basic option selection using the up arrow key, down arrow key, and enter arrow key\n
    
    Args:\n
    - *`options` (List of Strings) - Contains the options that the user can choose\n
    
    Returns:\n
    - *`chosen_option` (String) - The string for the option the user chose
    '''

    # Generates what each option will look like when displayed according to selected option
    def generate_display_list(options: [str], selected_index: int) -> [str]:
        # Append every option with the spaces or arrows added
        final_display_list = []
        for index, option in enumerate(options):
            if selected_index == index:
                final_display_list.append(f'> {option} <')
            else:
                final_display_list.append(f'  {option}  ')
        
        return final_display_list
    
    # Returns whether the current focused window is this scripts window
    def app_is_focused(main_window_handle: int) -> bool:
        # Get current focused window handle then compare them
        focused_window_handle: int = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        if main_window_handle == focused_window_handle:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    # Locks screen until refocused
    def unfocused_lock(prompt_setting: bool) -> None:
        # Wipe screen and show text if the setting is on
        if prompt_setting:
            system('cls')
            print("Refocus window to continue...")
        
        # Wait until screen is refocused    
        while not app_is_focused(main_window_handle):
            pass
            
        system('cls')

    # Clear screen and generate first set of options then run the main loop
    system('cls')
    selected_index = 0
    for option in generate_display_list(options, selected_index):
        print(option)
    
    # Main loop    
    while True:
        
        # First check if the app is focused or not
        if not app_is_focused(main_window_handle):
            # Lock screen until app is refocused then remake screen
            unfocused_lock(unfocused_prompt_setting)
        
        elif is_pressed('up'):
            selected_index -= 1
            
            # Lock until the key becomes unpressed
            while is_pressed('up'):
                pass
            
        elif is_pressed('down'):
            selected_index += 1
            
            # Lock until the key becomes unpressed
            while is_pressed('down'):
                pass
            
        elif is_pressed('enter'):
            return options[selected_index]
        
        else:
            continue
        
        # Only reached if screen locks or up and down key are pressed
        # Format selected index so it's in the allowed index range then remake screen
        selected_index %= len(options)
        system('cls')
        for option in generate_display_list(options, selected_index):
            print(option)
            
print(f"'{basic_arrow_selection(['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Delta'])}' was selected from the options!")
```

I was making it but whenever you pressed an arrow key, it would have a slight delay. And if you held the arrow key for a couple of seconds, there would be a large delay from whenever you released the key. If you held the up key for like 10 seconds it would take a solid 5-8 seconds to update the screen after letting go of the key. I traced it back to the key down flag being present long after letting go, almost like a queue. As such, I tried to use the `keyboard` modules `wait()` method and incorporate its `trigger_after_release` argument but after testing and checking the issues on its repo, it doesn't work as implemented. I tried to recreate it using curses on Windows but I'm still trying to debug it. The biggest issue as of yet is that whenever you unfocus from the terminal screen, it kinda just stops the script. How can I get this to not happen?
Bonus question: Still need to debug the weird formatting when you use the arrow keys and the error you get on line 73 when `quick_print()` is called. That function is just there for debugging right now but I'm curious as to why it raises an error. To get the issue, remove the try except on lines 27-29 which I put there just because of line 73. Would appreciate any pointers for these issues too.

Code:

```py
from ctypes import windll
import curses
import json
from time import sleep

class App:
    def __init__(self) -> object:
        # Add window and curses terminal related attribuites
        self.curses_terminal: curses.window = curses.initscr()
        self.window_handle: int = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        
        with open('settings.json', 'r') as settings_file:
            self.settings_dict: dict = json.load(settings_file)
            
        if self.settings_dict['GTFO Folder Path'] == '':
            self.gtfo_folder_path: str = ''
        else:
            self.gtfo_folder_path: str = self.settings_dict['GTFO Folder Path']
        
        # Set some important curses-terminal settings
        self.curses_terminal.keypad(True)
        self.curses_terminal.nodelay(True)
        curses.noecho()
        curses.cbreak()
        
    def quick_print(self, print_list: [str, object]) -> None:
        try:
            self.curses_terminal.addstr(*print_list)
        except curses.error:
            pass
        
    def generate_display_list(self, question: [str, object], options: [[str, object]], selected_index: int, refresh: bool = False) -> None:
        '''
        Adds the formatted text when displaying the prompt from `basic_prompt` to the screen\n
        
        Args:\n
        - *`question` (List of a string and `curses` objects) - First line which contains a question or statement along with any attribuites to the string using curses built-in properties such as `curses.COLOR_GREEN`\n
        - *`options` (List of Lists of a String and `curses` objects) - Contains the options that the user can choose along with any attribuites to the string using curses built-in properties such as `curses.COLOR_GREEN`\n
        - *`selected_index` (Integer) - The currently selected index
        - `refresh` (Boolean) - Whether to refresh the screen after loading the text
        
        Returns:\n
        - None
        '''
        # Clear terminal then add text to terminal
        self.curses_terminal.clear()
        question[0] += "\n"
        self.curses_terminal.addstr(*question)
        for index, option in enumerate(options):
            if selected_index == index:
                option[0] = f"> {option[0]} <\n"
                self.curses_terminal.addstr(*option)
            else:
                option[0] = f"  {option[0]}  \n"
                self.curses_terminal.addstr(*option)
        
        # Check whether to refresh
        if refresh:
            self.curses_terminal.refresh()
        
    def is_focused(self) -> bool:
        '''
        Checks if the terminal is focused or not\n
        
        Args:\n
        - None\n
        
        Returns:\n
        - *`focused` (Boolean) - Boolean representing whether the main window is currently focused or not
        '''
        sleep(5)
        if windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow() == self.window_handle:
            self.quick_print(["Is focused", curses.COLOR_RED])
            return True
        self.quick_print(["Is NOT focused", curses.COLOR_RED])
        return False
    
    def unfocused_lock(self) -> None:
        if self.settings_dict['Display Unfocused Prompt']:
            self.curses_terminal.clear()
            self.quick_print(["Refocus window to continue...", curses.COLOR_RED])
        while not self.is_focused():
            pass
        self.curses_terminal.clear()
        
        
    def basic_prompt(self, question: [str, object], options: [[str, object]]) -> str:
        '''
        Function for handling basic option selection using the up arrow key, down arrow key, and enter key\n
        
        Args:\n
        - *`question` (List of a string and `curses` objects) - First line which contains a question or statement along with any attribuites to the string using curses built-in properties such as `curses.COLOR_GREEN`\n
        - *`options` (List of Lists of a String and `curses` objects) - Contains the options that the user can choose along with any attribuites to the string using curses built-in properties such as `curses.COLOR_GREEN`\n
        
        Returns:\n
        - *`chosen_option` (String) - The string for the option the user chose
        '''
        # Clear terminal and load the initial screen
        selected_index = 0
        self.curses_terminal.clear()
        self.generate_display_list(question, options, selected_index, refresh=True)
        
        # Main loop
        while True:
            # Check if window is focused
            if not self.is_focused():
                self.unfocused_lock()
                self.generate_display_list(question, options, selected_index, refresh=True)
                continue
            
            try:
                pressed_key = self.curses_terminal.getkey()
            except curses.error:
                continue
            
            if pressed_key == 'KEY_UP':
                selected_index -= 1
            elif pressed_key == 'KEY_DOWN':
                selected_index += 1
            elif pressed_key == 'KEY_ENTER':
                return options[selected_index][0]
            else:
                continue
            selected_index %= len(options)
            self.generate_display_list(question, options, selected_index, refresh=True)
            
            
                
        
        
    def kill_terminal(self) -> None:
        '''
        Kills the `App` instance by killing the curses terminal\n
        
        Args:\n
        - None\n
        
        Returns:\n
        - None
        '''
        # Reset terminal settings before killing the curses terminal
        self.curses_terminal.keypad(False)
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()


x = App()
x.basic_prompt(["Whats the base?", curses.COLOR_RED], [["Alpha", curses.COLOR_GREEN], ["Bravo", curses.COLOR_GREEN], ["Charlie", curses.COLOR_YELLOW], ["Delta"]])
```

(Not polished yet so sorry for that)
(Editing to bump the question as I got no answers)